# C/C++ library for TIFF 6.0 and TTN2

Tags: c++, c, tiff, libtiff

Does anyone here know of a library where we could encode/decode TIFFv6 and TTN2?

It should be something we could use to ateast be able to convert bmp to these files and v.v.

Thanks.

Comment: For TIFF there's [libtiff](http://www.libtiff.org/).

Comment: There's also writing your own code. It isn't that difficult if you have the TIFF spec, especially if you only have a limitted format such as BMP thst you want to convert to and from.

Comment: I thought libtiff doesn't work for TIFF version 6?

Comment: @john: Do you have any suggestions as to where I can learn how to do such? How about TTN2?

Comment: you can take libtiff code and try to see how it works. and then try to re-write your own version for v6.

Comment: @Habagat_Seraphim Tiff 6 spec is here http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/tiff/TIFF6.pdf I'm afraid I've never heard to TTN2

Comment: As stated by @john, writing code to work with TIFF containers is pretty simple. Provide more details of what you're looking to do. Also, we've never heard of TTN2. Can you provide a link with info?